# Laravel 5.4 upload error with element-ui (vuejs)

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5.4

I'm using `element-ui` components with **VueJS**. All is working great, except when I come to uploading a file using the [file upload](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/upload) component:

**Upload Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\V1;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\{Config, Log};

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Attachments as AttachmentClass;

use App\Http\Requests\AttachmentRequest;

use Facades\App\Attachments;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AttachmentController extends Controller
{

/*
Upload a file for a given site
.................................................................. */

public function siteUpload (AttachmentRequest $request, $site_id)
    {
//    $this->request->file()
   Log::info ('AttachmentController::fileUpload for site [' . $site_id . '] | request = ' . $request) ;

   $attach = \App\Attachments::firstOrNew(['site_id' => $site_id]);
    }
```

}

**AttachmentRequest**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class AttachmentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return ['fileName' => 'required', 'file' => 'mimes:pdf, jpg, jpeg, bmp, png|size:5000'];
    }
}
```

However, when I upload an image to laravel, I get the following message:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/api/v1/upload/site/628 422 (Unprocessable Entity)
AttachmentsPanel.vue?8cf7:57 Fail Msg: Error: 422 {"error":"you did not send the required json in the body"}
```

I have a `Log::info` in the Laravel Controller that should display the file received.

However, it doesn't even get that far. The `FormRequest` guard seems to be throwing a 422 fit.

The error function of the upload component has some console.log entries, this is what the file portion returns:
[image]

I've chcked under **Network Tools** in Chrome and JSON data is being passed.
[image]

From the above, I don't think its the form upload control- since the data get passed successfully to Laravel.

Comment: My route looks like this: `Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/upload/site/{siteId}', 'AttachmentController@siteUpload')->name('upload.sites');`